# Automatic Google Street View Heading

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Is there an easy way to get Street View to automatically set the heading like the Street View Image API does?

I have Google Street View images embedded in my application and I would like to put a link on them that will direct the user to the full Google Street View, preferably with the same heading.  So far I can link to full Street View with the coordinates but not the heading, since I don't know the heading.

For a certain coordinate, the Street Map Image API will give me an image pointed at the coordinates given.  For example:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=300x150&location=38.9506254,-76.942316
[image: Google Street View API Image]

Using the an unofficial resource (http://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters) I can create a link to Google Street View, but I must provide a heading angle, which I don't have.  Here's an example with the Street View window parameters left off.

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=38.9506254,-76.942316

This works but does not give me a heading pointing toward the coordinates.  Instead, it points due north.  I assume I can host my own Street View page and get the heading as a vector from the nearest panorama to the target, as it appears Street View Image API does.  I would rather not if I don't have to if I can just embed a single link.

Also, is it safe to use the google map URL parameters?  They appear to be undocumented, but I can find references to the parameters I am using back in 2008 so they seem stable.

**Edit:**
To further elaborate on the difference between full Street View with URL parameters and Street View Image API, here's a diagram of what I get from both without specifying a heading.

[image: Street View and Street View Image API heading comparison]

Street View Image API will automatically point the POV camera at the target from the nearest Street View panorama when no heading is provided.  Full Street View, through URL parameters without heading, will point the POV camera due north.  I am looking for a easy way to mimic the Street View Image API behavior with Street View through URL parameters without having to pull panorama location information from google, though that looks like the only option.

Comment: *This works but does not give me a heading pointing toward the coordinates.* What do you mean here? I can look at any coordinate from any heading.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the heading that you want you can add a heading parameter in the querystring. Quoting from [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/index):

> **Heading** indicates the compass heading of the camera. Accepted values are from 0 to 360 (both values indicating North, with 90
>   indicating East, and 180 South). If no heading is specified, a value
>   will be calculated that directs the camera towards the specified
>   location, from the point at which the closest photograph was taken.

Comment: I am looking to set the heading when navigating to full street view, via something like http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=38.9506254,-76.942316, rather than using the google image API to get a static image.  What I actually ended up doing was calling a getPanoramaByLocation, which gives me the coordinates of the view point google will return for my target location.  Then I construct my url to full google street view using the supplied panorama location and the calculated angle from the panorama location to my intended target.